# create a MAC using key from bytearray

Tags: java, key, hmac

I have a bytearray and want to make a Key-objecct out of it, which is going to be used
to initialize an Mac-object. But I dont know how to make a key-object for this, the right type of key and so on. Some help would be greatly appreciated;

```
byte[] key2 = rsaDec.doFinal(encKey2); //assume this is correct
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");

Key macKey = new Key //heres the issue at hand
mac.init(macKey);
byte[] message = ... //this will be retrieved
mac.update(message);
byte[] macVal = mac.doFinal();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be:

```
 String keyString = "theKeyImUsing";
 SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacMD5");
 mac.init(macKey);
```

If you already have the byte[] then just pass it:

```
     SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(myByteArray, "HmacMD5");
```